# NoSuchMethodException while accessing Kotlin Data class using reflection

Tags: java, android, kotlin, reflection

I keep getting the following error while tryign to use reflection to access a kotlin data class
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [interface java.util.List, class java.lang.Boolean]`

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList();
boolean isValid = false;
Class[] type = { List.class, Boolean.class };
Class dataClass = Class.forName("com.randome.model.Data");
Constructor DataConstructor = dataClass.getConstructor(type); // problem here 
Object[] dataObject = { names, isValid };
Object data = inAppContactDataConstructor.newInstance(dataObject);
```

// Data Class

```
@Parcelize
data class Data(
    val names: List<String>,
    val isValid: Boolean
): Parcelable
```

Comment: It seems that you'll need to use `boolean.class`, or `Boolean.TYPE`, instead, since "On the JVM, non-nullable values of this type are represented as values of the primitive type `boolean`." ([Source](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-boolean/)). Tested, and it works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe proguard is removing that constructor because it doesn't think anyone is using it. When I print out dataClass.getConstructors().length, the result is zero items.

Try adding the @Keep annotation to your data class:

```
@Keep
@Parcelize
data class Data(
    val names: List<String>,
    val isValid: Boolean
): Parcelable
```

I tried it on your code and it got rid of the exception. Oh, and I also had to change:

```
Class[] type = { List.class,Boolean.class };
```

to:

```
Class[] type = { List.class,boolean.class };
```